# UITableViewCell background color animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uiviewanimation

I want to add infinite color changing animation for cell. Code above not working properly. It start animating from color with alpha (not from color I set first) after a little glitch (0.3 sec or so).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SuggestionCell"];

    if ([indexPath isEqual:_animatingCellIndexPath]) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse 
            | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat 
            | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
            animations:^{
                cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
            }
            completion:NULL];
    }
    else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:false];
    _animatingCellIndexPath = indexPath; 
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[_animatingCellIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
}
```

It's possible to set `backgroundView` for cell and animate it, then everything works fine, except that separator is not animating.

Answer (score 0):

Try it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
  willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Example:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.row == 5) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


    } else {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.row == 5) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse
         | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
         | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                         animations:^{
                             cell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
                         }
                         completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited with an example that worked for me. If it still doesn't work for you please upload your code, and describe what does happen (maybe the problem is not related to that at all)

Comment: Thank you. Yes it work if table is just loaded. Try to change `indexPath.row == 5` to `[indexPath isEqual:_animatingCellIndexPath]` and add this code wor animation start: `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:false];
    _animatingCellIndexPath = indexPath;
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[_animatingCellIndexPath] 
}`

Comment: Comment is truncated a little. See updated question.